# Escaping < in graph name SPARQL

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, named-graphs

I accidentally created a graph with a name that begins with `<` and ends with `>`.

If I try to clear the graph from the Virtuoso server by --

```
clear graph <graph_name>
```

-- or --

```
clear graph <<graph_name>>
```

-- or  --

```
clear graph <\<graph_name\>>
```

-- it does not work.  They all give similar errors:

`*** Error 37000: [Virtuoso Driver][Virtuoso Server]SQ074: Line 1: SPARQL compiler, line 1: syntax error at '<' before '<graph_name>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<` and `>` are illegal in URIs so the parser is going to get upset if used directly.

CLEAR can be thought of as a short form of DELETE so you can try:

```
DELETE { GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o } }
WHERE { GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o } 
        FILTER (str(?g) = '<graph_name>')
      }
```

Comment: After several hours of searching you just saved my day. Thank you very much!